# ANTLR C# ASTLabelType Problem

Tags: c#, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to change the type of nodes that my parser generates from 'CommonTree' to my custom type 'ASTNode'.

I have set the options in my parser...

```
options 
{
  language = CSharp3;
  output = AST;
  ASTLabelType = ASTNode;
  tokenVocab = MyLexer;
}
```

...but when I generate my parser code, I get the following error on every rule. E,g. the statement rule...

```
'MyParser.statement_return' does not implement interface member
'Antlr.Runtime.IAstRuleReturnScope.Tree'. 

'MyParser.statement_return.Tree' cannot implement
'Antlr.Runtime.IAstRuleReturnScope.Tree' because it does not have the matching return
type of 'object'.
```

My AST worked fine witout using ASTLabelType. Any ideas how to fix this?
Here's the source for ASTNode...

```
public class ASTNode : CommonTree
{
    List<ASTNode> children;

    public ASTNode() {}
    public ASTNode(ASTNode node) : base(node) {} 
    public ASTNode(CommonToken token) { this.token = token; }
    public ASTNode(int tokenType) { this.token = new CommonToken(tokenType); }

    public override ITree DupNode()
    {
        return new ASTNode(this);
    }

    public void AddChild(ASTNode t)
    {
        if (children == null) { children = new List<ASTNode>(); }
        children.Add(t);
    }

    public virtual string DisplayText() { return token.Text+"<AST>"; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the source of your `ASTNode`?

Comment: That tree looks okay to me. Could you post your grammar as well?

Comment: I'm using a grammar out of the Language Pattern book to practice with...http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/code/IR/Vec/VecMathAST.g

Comment: If you're using the VecMathAST grammar, then what is `tokenVocab = MyLexer` doing in there?

Comment: Ok, lol, all I did was seperate the lexer stuff into its own file. Everything is working fine when using standard CommonTree, it's just when I add 'ASTLabelType = ASTNode' that I get this error.

Comment: Okay, I tried to use the `CSharp3`, but it relies on classes from the .NET runtime that are not present in my Mono installation. I can't help you, unfortunately. If I were you, I'd try the ANTLR mailing list. Be sure to add all the information in your question at once. Good luck.

Comment: Continued here: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/yjf2fbxor25om2ew